# OK if the number of non-empty cells is a multiple of number 4

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have **12** **non-empty cells**:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
```

I usually use the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")=12,"OK","ERROR")
```

But if there are **8 non-empty cells** I also want it to be `OK`, so I change it to:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")=12,"OK",IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")=8,"OK","ERROR"))
```

I need to add more `IF` functions for all numbers multiple of **4**, as they are all `OK`.

Is there any way to already warn a formula that whenever it is a multiple of **4**, such as **4**, **8**, **12**, **16**, **20**, **24** and so on, return the value `OK`?

Comment: I think `MOD` is the function you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know this function and was not finding it.

If you want, create an answer to my question that I will mark as a solution to the problem, it solved perfectly!

Comment: ```=IF(MOD(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>"),4)=0,"OK","ERROR")```, This formula was perfect for my need, if you want to use it in the answer as an indication.

Comment: Nah, it's ok. I just gave a hint. You developed the formula on your own, so feel free to self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the tip given by the user @Calculuswhiz in this comment → [OK if the number of non-empty cells is a multiple of number 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66991982/ok-if-the-number-of-non-empty-cells-is-a-multiple-of-number-4?noredirect=1#comment118416855_66991982), a simple way to solve the problem is to work with the `MOD` function, which *returns the result of the module operator, the rest of a division operation*.

Then, when the remainder is equal to `0`, it is automatically noted that the number is a multiple of which it is trying to divide, in which case the formula that solves the problem would be as follows:

```
=IF(MOD(COUNTIF(A:A,"<>"),4)=0,"OK","ERROR")
```